# How to convert dataframe output to json format and then Normalize the data?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I am running a sql and output i am reading as pandas df. Now i need to convert the data  in to json and need to normalize the data. I tried to_json  but this give partial solution.

Dataframe output:

```
| SalesPerson   | ContactID |
|12345  |Tom|
|12345  |Robin|
|12345  |Julie|
```

Expected JSON:

```
 {"SalesPerson": "12345", "ContactID":"Tom","Robin","Julie"}
```

Please see below code which i tried.

```
q = Select COL1,  SalesPerson   , ContactIDfrom table;


df = pd.read_sql(q, sqlconn)

df1=df.iloc[:, 1:2]


df2 = df1.to_json(orient='records')
```

## also to_json result bracket which i also dont need.

Comment: Your expected output is invalid JSON

Comment: My bad.. corrected
{"SalesPerson": 12345, "ContactID":["Tom","Robin","Julie"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('SalesPerson').apply(lambda x: pd.Series({
    'ContactID': x['ContactID'].values
})).reset_index().to_json(orient='records')
```

Output (pretty printed):

```
[
  {
    "SalesPerson": 1,
    "ContactID": ["Tom", "Robin", "Julie"]
  },
  {
    "SalesPerson": 2,
    "ContactID": ["Jack", "Mike", "Mary"]
  }
]
```

Comment: This work fine. Thanks!
just one more thing. 
if i dont want  start and end brackets [ ]  then what i need to modify.

Comment: That would make it invalid JSON.